# How to cache GoogleAccountCredential between app launch (Android)?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'd like to let the user log in once to use Google Drive SDK v2 and don't ask him every time the app is launched. How can i do it since `GoogleAccountCredential` does not implement `Serializable` and `Parcelable` to save it in persistent storage? How can i check if the user is logged in?

Now i have to ask the user to log in every time the app is launched:

```
GoogleAccountCredential googleDriveCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA);
startActivityForResult(googleDriveCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(), ACTION_LINK_GOOGLE_DRIVE);
```

I'd prefer to do it like it's done in Dropbox Android SDK:

```
DbxAccountManager accountManager = DropboxAccountManagerHolder.get().getAccountManager();
if (!accountManager.hasLinkedAccount())
    DropboxAccountManagerHolder.get().getAccountManager()
                    .startLink(this, ACTION_LINK_DROPBOX);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be done automatically: https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/android.
The problem is to check if it's logged in. For this you have to get credential token and and handle an exception:

> When using a Drive service using the special Android auth utilities:
>   If the user has already authorized the application the Drive service
>   will be authorized and work as expected. If the user has not
>   authorized the application using the Drive service will throw an
>   UserRecoverableAuthException containing an Intent that can be used to
>   display to the user the authorization grant dialog.

```
try {
  GoogleAccountCredential credential =
      GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(mContext, DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE);
  credential.setSelectedAccountName(mAccount.name);
  // Trying to get a token right away to see if we are authorized
  credential.getToken();
```